# Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\ProfessionalsController::$user

Tags: laravel

I want to add the user while adding a vendor, but it shows me error. I have created the object of class User. This is my code:

```
    <?php

        namespace App\Http\Controllers;

        use Session;
        use App\Vendors;
        use App\User;
        use App\Category;
        use App\Location;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;

        class VendorsController extends Controller
        { 
            public function store(Request $request)
            {

                 $this->validate($request, [
                    'name' => 'required|min:2|max:20',
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'
                ]);

                $data = array(
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'email' => $request->email,
                    'role' => 'Vendor'
                );

                $this->user->fill($data);
                $this->user->save(); 

$professional = Professional::create([
            'user_id' => $this->user,
            'contact_number' => $request->contact_number,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'about_us' => $request->about_us,
            'category_id' => $request->category_id
        ]);

                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }
```

But I am getting this error:

> Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\ProfessionalsController::$user

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did it work to u?

Comment: you have created the object of class User where?